# How to set uploaded file's name to an input type:text on javascript in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, html-input

I want to add a File Upload control to my html page like below.

```
<input class="form-control valid" id="rptScreenShot" type="text" style="float:left;" runat="server"
                               data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Report Sample must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '600'." 
                               data-val-maxlength-max="600" value="" aria-invalid="false" />
<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    Browse <input class="form-control" id="upld_sample1" type="file" name="file_rptsample1" style="display: none;">
</label>
```

What I could not manage to do is to catch the selected file after a user browsed a file and set it to the value of rptScreenShot via javascript or jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below?

```js
$("#upld_sample1").on("change", function(e){
  console.log("Fileinfo:", e.target.files[0])
  $("#rptScreenShot").val(e.target.files[0].name)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control valid" id="rptScreenShot" type="text" style="float:left;" runat="server" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Report Sample must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '600'." data-val-maxlength-max="600"
  value="" aria-invalid="false" />
<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    Browse <input class="form-control" id="upld_sample1" type="file" name="file_rptsample1" style="display: none;">
</label>
```

Comment: But without having the full path of the file, how can I upload it to the server from user's local after clicking the save button? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: All info is in `e.target.files[0]`, your question asked only for name inside the input

Comment: @JesusHamdi You typically use `FormData` in JS to pass uploaded file to server, where the file itself is appended and you don't need the path

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the complete path in e.target.files[0] ? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: @JesusHamdi Like I said, you don't need the path, you append the file to `FormData` and send it to the backend, try to go through some online tutorials. Do accept the answer because it answers your original question as is :)

Comment: I will create another question for sending the file to the server after working on it sometime more then. thanks for your time.